# Ionic Error Object(...) is not a function at NativePageTransitions.fade

Tags: javascript, cordova, npm, ionic3, ionic4

I am trying to do fade transition for page transition. I have installed [native-page-transition plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/native-page-transitions) in beta version.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions
$ npm install @ionic-native/native-page-transitions@beta
```

and added in providers in app.module.ts

```
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx';

providers: [
    NativePageTransitions,
]
```

In page, i am using it as

```
import { NativePageTransitions, NativeTransitionOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx';

constructor(private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions){}

Animation(){
    let options: NativeTransitionOptions = {}
    this.nativePageTransitions.fade(options);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
```

But when i run the script and run the function, it shows me the following error

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at NativePageTransitions.fade

Please help me get rid of the error.

**Ionic Info**:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, browser 5.0.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, (and 12 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   NodeJS            : v10.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: There seems to be issues with using `ionic-native` v 5.x with ionic 3... I suggest you try using `ionic-native v4 https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/native-page-transitions/

Answer (score 1):

It is because of version of `@ionic-native/native-page-transitions`

Make sure your `@ionic-native/native-page-transitions` version is same as `@ionic/native/core`

**package.json**

**Before**

```
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^5.13.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.20.0",
```

**After**

```
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.20.0",
```

Hope this will help!!!